# Devolver variable a Ajax desde Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, aspx

Quiero devolver un el valor de una variable a `ajax` (`IDAUTT`), pero lo que me saca por pantalla es `undefined`, alguien sabe que hago mal? Gracias de antemano. El código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=ddlFondos]").change(function () {
            var lista = {};
            var idAut = $('#IdAutor').val();
            lista.Autor = $("[id*=ddlFondos]").val();
            lista.Temas = $("[id*=ddlAutores]").val();
            lista.Lugar = $("[id*=ddlLugar]").val();
            lista.Fecha = $("[id*=ddlFecha]").val();
            lista.IDAUTT = $("#IDAUTT").val();

            if (lista.Autor != "")

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Consulta.aspx/SaveUser",
                data: '{lista: ' + JSON.stringify(lista) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(lista.Autor);
                    alert(lista.IDAUTT);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>


        public class Lista
    {
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public string Temas { get; set; }
        public string Lugar { get; set; }
        public string Fecha { get; set; }
        public int IDAUTT { get; set; }
    }

[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static int SaveUser(Lista lista)
    {

        Consulta Consultaz = new Consulta();
        var Autor = lista.Autor;
        var Temas = lista.Temas;
        var Lugar = lista.Lugar;
        var Fecha = lista.Fecha;
        object IdAutorzz;
        var Fondoz = HttpContext.Current.Session["FondoURL"];
        int Fondo = Convert.ToInt32(Fondoz);
        int IdAutor;
        // int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["idFondo"], out Fondo);
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Consultaz.cadConex);

        var data = lista;

        if (Autor != null)
        {
            var ConcultaAutor = $"SELECT ID_AUTOR FROM AUTORES where [NOMBRE] + ' ' + [APELLIDO1] + ' ' + [APELLIDO2] LIKE '%{Autor}%'";
            conn.Open();
            var IdAutorz = new SqlCommand(ConcultaAutor, conn);
            IdAutorzz = IdAutorz.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();

            IdAutor = Convert.ToInt32(IdAutorzz);
        }
        else
            IdAutor = 0;

        Lista id = new Lista();
        id.IDAUTT = 1;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);

    }
```

Los valores me dan un poco igual ahora ya que es una prueba, por eso le digo lo que vale de manera explícita. También probé con esa variable que ahora no está en uso, `var idAut = $('#IdAutor').val();`, pero no se ejecutaba el método. Sospecho que puede ser por el `data` pero soy un poco novato y no tengo mucha idea jeje.
En sí lo que al final quiero devolver es `IdAutor` para que una vez esté en el `ajax` poder trabajar con este.

Answer (score 0):

El problema reside en que estas definiendo la respuesta AJAX como `respuesta` en lugar de `lista` el método AJAX debería ser así:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Consulta.aspx/SaveUser",
  data: '{lista: ' + JSON.stringify(lista) + '}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(response.IDAUTT); // mostramos la propiedad del objeto
  }
});
```

Comment: Pero el problema es que "lista.Autor", "lista.Temas", "lista.Lugar", "lista.Fecha" los necesito ya que el IDAUTT depende de estos valores.

Comment: No puedo comentar en la pregunta inicial, así que te lo pregunto aquí, entonces: 
¿La variable lista.IDAUTT llega a estar definida antes de hacer el xhr?
¿La información que llega a Consulta.aspx/SaveUser, es correcta?

Comment: Si, lo que yo quiero enviar es el valor de "IdAutor" que bueno en este caso le di uno simplemente para probar, y en "public static string SaveUser(Lista lista)" en realidad sería "int" pero bueno eso ya lo probé, voy a editar esa parte.

Comment: He editado la respuesta ¿Puedes probar de editar la propiedad success del procedimiento ajax, y comprobar el resultado en la consola en el navegador? Debería devolverte un objeto con la propiedad IDAUTT===1.

Comment: Perdona por tardar en contestar, al final, creo que no es posible hacer lo que quería ya que mi idea era actualizar un "panel" en aspx, pero de la manera que lo cargo solo se puede mediante "updatepanel" asique tengo que cambiar todo el planteamiento jeje gracias por la ayuda :)